# Saving images in app Folder?

Tags: java, android, image, gallery

I am making a chat application in which user also has the option to send pictures. I want to save the images to the application folder so I can access those images to fill the chat window up with previous messages with pictures and text. So my question is how can I add an image to the application folder?
Thanks

Comment: i assume you mean to the package applications drawable folder.?? not sure you can do that. you have to use the apps cache storage or to an  internal/external storage folder which you can create and store the images there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first you have to create  your app name folder into sd card then you have to write your file/image into it

```
String SDCardRoot = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
String filename = "fileName" + ".jpg";
File myDir = new File(SDCardRoot + "/AppName");
myDir.mkdirs();
File file = new File(myDir, filename);
FileOutputStream fileOutput = new FileOutputStream(file);

//write the file into the sdcard folder specify your buffer , bufferLength 

fileOutput.write(buffer, 0, bufferLength);
fileOutput.close();
```

then only you can access the files from app folder

```
       File imgFile;
       String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/AppName/" + ".jpg";
        imgFile = new File(path);

        if (imgFile.exists()) {
            Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imgFile.getAbsolutePath());
            imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        }
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help!